# Let $f : R_+ \to R $ be a function that satisfies for all $x > 0, f(x) \geq 0$ and $f$ is stricly concave, show that $f$ is sub additive

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a (differentiable) function that satisfies the following
>
> - $f(x) = 0\iff x =0$
> - $\forall x > 0, f(x) \geq 0$
> - $f$ is stricly concave
>
> Show that for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}_+$ we have $f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$

My lecturer did the following proof in class

*Lecturers proof:* For any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}_+$ we have $$f(x + y) - f(y) = \int_o^x f'(s+y)ds \leq \int_o^x f'(s) ds = f(x) - f(0) = f(x)$$
which implies $f(x+y) - f(y) \leq f(x)$ which implies $f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$. $\square$

---

Now the only part in the proof I can't understand is how we can conclude $$\int_o^x f'(s+y)ds \leq \int_o^x f'(s) ds$$

Why does this inequality hold? Is it because $f$ is concave so it's derivative $f'$ is monotonically decreasing, hence $f'(s+y) \leq f'(s)$ for any $y \geq 0$, thus by the properties of integrals we arrive at the following inequality?

Comment: Yes, this is the argument.

Comment: yes. a concave function means that its derivative is monotone decreasing whenever the function is differentiable.

Comment: It seems to me the statement is valid with no differentiability assumption. It should be possible to obtain using the inequalities only. I will look for it.

Comment: @szw1710 Both $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ lie above the line segment from $(0,f(0))$ to $(x+y,f(x+y))$, hence so does the fourth point of the parallelogram with vertices $(0,0)$, $(x,f(x))$, $(y,f(y))$, $(x+y,f(x)+f(y))$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen , you recalled me a beutiful argument connected with Wright-concavity. I will write it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strict concavity is not necessary, concavity is enough. As I said in my comment above, the differentiability assumption is also redundant.

Let $x,y\geqslant 0.$ If $x+y=0$ then $x=y=0$ and it is nothing to prove: $f(0+0)\leqslant f(0)+f(0)$, both sides are zero.

Let $x+y>0$. Then $$x=\frac{y}{x+y}\cdot 0+\frac{x}{x+y}\cdot(x+y).$$ The (nonnegative) scalars $\dfrac{x}{x+y}$ and $\dfrac{y}{x+y}$ sum up to $1$. By concavity  and $f(0)=0$ we get $$f(x)\geqslant\frac{x}{x+y}\cdot f(x+y).$$ Similarly (by symmetry) $$f(y)\geqslant\frac{y}{x+y}\cdot f(x+y).$$ Summing up these inequalities we arrive at $$f(x)+f(y)\geqslant f(x+y)$$ and the proof is finished.